# Usefulness of CloudFlare for clients of Argentina

Tags: domain-name-system, cloudflare

We are currently hosting an important site in the US with a CloudFlare pro subscription.

Since most of the people that visit the site are from Argentina, we are considering migrating the server to Argentina but we are unsure of we should keep CloudFlare enabled.

Any thoughts or ideas?

- I'm only interested in knowing the performance difference
- Their edge servers seem to be detailed [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/network-map) and it seems they don't have anything in latam.

Comment: Sounds like something you should ask Cloudflare directly?  My guess is that the answer would depend on how close their edge servers were to Argentina.

Comment: Have you done a risk and benefit analysis?

Comment: Phil, I did and currently waiting for their answer. I wanted to get informed first, I'm not sure they will be 100% honest.

@mailq Since this question will influence whether to migrate to Argentina or not, I'm not able yet to test this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would generally still help speed things up and we'll definitely still cut things down like forum or comment spam.

That being said, we currently don't have datacenters in South America & visitors would currently get routed to a datacenter in the United States (we're exploring the possibility of adding a datacenter in South America). Some visitors might see increased latency because of this.